# A <div> of mine isn't going where it's supposed to, and the only way I know how to fix it pushes the <p> out of the <div>

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` that is supposed to fit under one `<div>` and to the left of another `<div>`, and it's going under where the `<div>` to the left ends because of its `clear:both` property for its id in my CSS file. But if I change that property in any way, and the `<div>` goes to where it's supposed to. If that sounded confusing, that's okay, because I know I probably did a terrible job of wording it, so I'll just show you.

[image: 1920x1080 view of a site for 1366x768 PCs. Displays layout along with problematic <code><div></code> and where it should be.]

Here's the code for the site, both its HTML and its CSS. Again, the `<div>`s I'm concerned about are "text", which is the `<div>` that's being misplaced. The `<div>` that should be right above it is the one with the text "About me", its id is "main". The `<div>` with the 3 pictures in it has the id of "picture".

The HTML:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <title>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="banner" id="banner"></div>
    <a href="index.html"><div id="button"><p id="p1">Home</p></div></a>
    <a href="about.html"><div id="button"><p id="p1">About Me</p></div></a>
    <a href="career.html"><div id="button"><p id="p1">Career</p></div></a>
    <a href="school.html"><div id="fixbutton"><p id="p1">Schooling</p></div></a>
    <div id="main"><p align="center" style="font-size:400%">About Me</p></div>
    <div id="picture"><img height="575" width="751" src="4-photos-art.jpg"/></div>
    <div id="additionaltext"></div>
    <div id="text"><p id="p1">As an individual, I like to think of myself as a very artistic and creative person. My hobbies are mostly just me drawing and playing my instrument. My ideal career would be in art and/or music.</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
#banner {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;float:left;width:30%;height:71px;border:2px solid;
}

#button {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;border:2px solid;float:left;width:15%;height:71px;
}

#fixbutton {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;border:2px solid;float:left;width:15%;height:71px;
}


#main {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;height:204px;width:23%;float:left;border:2px solid;
}

#picture {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;height:575px;width:55%;float:left;border:2px solid;
}

#text {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;height:650px;width:23%;border:2px solid;text-align:center;clear:right;
}

#additionaltext {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;height:575px;width:21%;float:right;border:2px solid;
}

#p1 {
    text-align:center;font-size:150%;
}

#button:hover {
    background-color:#ffff99;
}

#fixbutton:hover {
    background-color:#ffff99;
}
```

Comment: can you include the css that you use?

Comment: I did, it's the last content on the question.

Comment: ohh I see is that all? all I see was background hahaha anyways I will create a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this edit will help you :)

I just change your div to inside of main div. Also i make few change on css about pixels.

```css
#banner {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;float:left;width:30%;height:71px;border:2px solid;
}

#button {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;border:2px solid;float:left;width:15%;height:71px;
}

#fixbutton {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;border:2px solid;float:left;width:15%;height:71px;
}


#main {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;height:204px;width:23%;float:left;border:2px solid;
}

#picture {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;height:575px;width:55%;float:left;border:2px solid;
}

#text {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;height:370px;width:100%;border:2px solid;text-align:center;clear:right;
}

#additionaltext {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;height:575px;width:20%;float:right;border:2px solid;
}

#p1 {
    text-align:center;font-size:150%;
}

#button:hover {
    background-color:#ffff99;
}

#fixbutton:hover {
    background-color:#ffff99;
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <title>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="banner" id="banner"></div>
    <a href="index.html"><div id="button"><p id="p1">Home</p></div></a>
    <a href="about.html"><div id="button"><p id="p1">About Me</p></div></a>
    <a href="career.html"><div id="button"><p id="p1">Career</p></div></a>
    <a href="school.html"><div id="fixbutton"><p id="p1">Schooling</p></div></a>
    <div id="main"><p align="center" style="font-size:400%">About Me</p
      >
  <div id="text"><p id="p1">As an individual, I like to think of myself as a very artistic and creative person. My hobbies are mostly just me drawing and playing my instrument. My ideal career would be in art and/or music.</p></div>
  </div>
    <div id="picture"><img height="575" width="751" src="4-photos-art.jpg"/></div>
    <div id="additionaltext"></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! This problem was prevalent throughout my entire site so far, so this really helped.

Answer (score 2):

Here I fix your html and css. Goodluck!

```css
#banner {
background-color:#FFFFFF;float:left;width:30%;height:71px;border:2px solid;
}

#button {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:2px solid;
    float:left;
    width:15%;
    height:71px;
}
#fixbutton {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:2px solid;
    float:left;
    width:15%;
    height:71px;
}
#main {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    height:204px;
    width:23%;
    float:left;border:2px solid;
}
#picture {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    height:575px;
    width:55%;
    float:left;
    border:2px solid;
}
#text {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    height:361px;
    width:100%;
    border:2px solid;
    text-align:center;
    clear:right;
}
#additionaltext {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    height:575px;
    width:20%;
    float:right;
    border:2px solid;
}
#p1 {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:150%;
}
#button:hover {
    background-color:#ffff99;
}
#fixbutton:hover {
    background-color:#ffff99;
}
.clear{clear:both;}

p{margin-bottom:0}
```

```html
<div id="banner" id="banner"></div>
     <div class "menu">
       <a href="index.html"><div id="button"><p id="p1">Home</p></div></a>
        <a href="about.html"><div id="button"><p id="p1">About Me</p></div></a>
        <a href="career.html"><div id="button"><p id="p1">Career</p></div></a>
        <a href="school.html"><div id="fixbutton"><p id="p1">Schooling</p></div></a>
     </div>
     <div class="clear">
     
     </div>
      <div id="main">
            <p align="center" style="font-size:400%">About Me</p>
             <div id="text">
        <p id="p1">As an individual, I like to think of myself as a very artistic and creative person. My hobbies are mostly just me drawing and playing my instrument. My ideal career would be in art and/or music.</p>
            </div>
      </div>
     
      <div id="picture">
        <img height="575" width="751" src="4-photos-art.jpg"/>
       </div>
    <div id="additionaltext"></div>
```